# Large images load slowly when sending via php vs straight links

Tags: php, image, apache

When we output images via PHP with `image_jpeg` or `file_get_contents` it takes more than twice as long as when we use straight links to the jpg files.
These files are about 180kb.
With our thumbnails (4kb images) there's not much of a time difference between the link and output via PHP.

Anyone know of a why PHP output is slower with larger files and a way to fix it?

Comment: it's just a plain image output or does it have any processing on it ?

Comment: Unless you're processing the image in some way, why not simply use readfile() to stream the file rather than file_get_contents() which has the overhead of loading the file to memory first

Comment: just a plain image output

Answer (score 3):

All I can think of is that it is being parsed twice when parsed through PHP, instead of directly sending it to the client. Because file_get_contents does what it says, it reads the contents, then sends it to the client. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

There is different between image_jpeg and file_get_contents. The first is a gd function that creates a jpeg and this take time. The second just reads data from a file.

The problem is how you output it to the browser. If you don't take appropriate measures, content is never cached, so the browser has to download it every time. Static images are always cached by the browser and after the first load, takes almost no time (just a HEAD request).

Try this code:

```
function CachedFileResponse($thefile,$nocache=0) {
  if (!file_exists($thefile)) {
    error_log('cache error: file not found: '.$thefile);
    header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found',true,404);
  } else {
    $lastmodified=gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', filemtime($thefile));
    $etag = '"'.md5($lastmodified.filesize($thefile).$thefile).'"';
    header('ETag: '.$etag);
    header('Last-Modified: '.$lastmodified);
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=3600');
    header('Expires: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time()+86400));
    $ext=strtolower(substr($thefile,strrpos($thefile,'.')+1));
    $fname=substr($thefile,strrpos($thefile,'/')+1);
    if ($ext=='jpg' || $ext=='jpeg') {
      header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    } elseif ($ext=='gif') {
      header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    } elseif ($ext=='png') {
      header('Content-Type: image/png');
    } else {
      header('Content-Type: application/binary');
    }
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($thefile));
    header('Content-Disposition: filename="'.$fname.'"');

    $ifmodifiedsince = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) ? stripslashes($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) : false;
    $ifnonematch = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) ? stripslashes($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) : false;
    if ($nocache || (!$ifmodifiedsince && !$ifnonematch) ||
       ($ifnonematch && $ifnonematch != $etag) ||
       ($ifmodifiedsince && $ifmodifiedsince != $lastmodified)) {
      error_log('cache miss: '.$thefile);
      $fp = fopen($thefile, 'rb');
      fpassthru($fp);
      fclose($fp);
    } else {
      error_log('cache hit: '.$thefile);
      header("HTTP/1.0 304 Not Modified",true,304);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks the thing is here we don't want caching because image that is being sent depends on session variable and also probably won't be viewed more than once.

Comment: So what are you expecting to happen? An image created on the fly with gd2 from php will always take more time than a static image served by apache.

Comment: even not from gd2 - echo file_get_contents also takes longer with larger images (like 180kb), with images that are 4kb there's almost no difference.

Comment: the reason we don't have straight links to the images is for security purposes

Comment: I explained why this happens if you pass through PHP and it's the caching issue. Direcy links are CACHED locally by the browser. PHP scripts are NOT CACHED. Do you understand?

Comment: Try my code and you will see no difference with big images. You want dinamic images, speed and no caching: this is not possible. Choose your destiny.